# Use PayPal From Website Form

Tags: paypal

Requirements state that I build a form that collects user's PayPal login info and charges the user's PayPal account a fixed price **without having the user leave the website**.

I am beginning to think this is not possible.  Can someone kindly suggest a solution that comes close to meeting the requirements?  I am not certain what's possible and what's not possible with PayPal.

Comment: The requirement is not reasonable.  I would never reveal my PayPal login details to a third party website.

Comment: @RichieHindle what is the closest solution I can offer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know (which is why I left a comment rather than an answer. :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest solution to having the user pay without leaving the website is PayPal digital goods express checkout.

Here is an example to show you how it works:

http://jmsliu.com/1307/integrate-paypal-digital-goods-express-checkout-into-website.html

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a solution for what you are trying to do.  In order for the buyer to login and pay with PayPal, they would have to leave your site and go to the PayPal login page.  You could set up a billing agreement so that they only have to log into PayPal once.  With a billing agreement, you would be able to charge the buyer's PayPal account when you are needing to.  You would just need to have the buyer go through the flow initially and get sent over to PayPal to login and agreen to the billing agreement.  Then when you want to charge them again in the future, you would just need to reference the billing agreement id.